# Why does Pasting Controls on a Microsoft Access Form takes a long time?

Tags: vba, ms-access, office365, ms-office

I have been working with Microsoft Access for quite a while - and I have a form with a Tab Control, containing about 12 pages, each page has a subform, showing data from a table - and I am trying to add and rename a new tab, but it seems to cause the database to 'freeze' even though it does not say 'not responding' and it just sits there for a few minutes before successfully renaming.

I have already checked on control limits - I have around 300 controls on the form (aware that the limit is around 750). I already checked on potentially conflicting names of controls.

I also tried importing the form to another database file, and compacting/repairing the existing database.  Same issue happens.  Any thoughts on what else I can do?

I am trying to determine if there is something I can do to eliminate this dely.

Comment: One thing it's worthy to do in MS Access (specially if you have VBA code in it) is sometimes decompile it and then compile it again and making the compact/repair

Comment: @tdmsoares, I tried the decompile and compile action - I am fairly convinced it was due to the microsoft update attempting to install in the background, as after rebooting and following the steps I left below, it seems to be working much better.  But true, for those that don't know how to decompile, it is very useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, here is what I recently found, and not sure exactly why, but it solved my issue.

1. I turned off my computer and turned it back on again (not a restart, but a full shut down and power on)
2. I installed some updates that were hanging in the background
3. I 'killed' the 'office click to run' process that was in task manager
4. I performed the action again, with NO other programs running

Doing these four steps - and not sure why, or if it was just one step or the combination, but now copying and pasting the controls works fine on the form again.

While it fixed my issue - and I am putting my comments here for the next person - I am not sure which of these actions would have had any effect, or why.

Comment: One of my PCs is very slow whenever there are auto updates in the background doing their thing (downloading, implementing, etc).  Don't know why this 1 pc only but I've come to recognize the symptom - and just have to wait till it is complete before using it